# Display authors list with permalink and sort by comments count

Tags: php, comments

I would like to create a Page where display a list of the authors sort by comments count.
I found only this on the web:

in functions.php

```
function top_comment_authors($amount = 5) {
global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results('
SELECT
COUNT(comment_author_email) AS comments_count, comment_author_email, comment_author, comment_author_url
FROM '.$wpdb->comments.'
WHERE comment_author_email != "" AND comment_type = "" AND comment_approved = 1
GROUP BY comment_author_email
ORDER BY comments_count DESC, comment_author ASC
LIMIT '.$amount
);
$output = "<ul>";
foreach($results as $result) {
$output .= "<li><a href='".$result->comment_author_url."'>".$result->comment_author."</a></li>";
}
$output .= "</ul>";
echo $output;
}
```

Then I called back the function in my Template Page:

```
<?php top_comment_authors(); ?>
```

But the author link ($result->comment_author_url) doesn't work correctly. The link connects me to the same page where I am currently. 
Any advice?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

normally in wordpress the comment author link can be displayed using,

```
<?php echo get_comment_author_link( $comment_ID ); ?>
```